# .htaccess 2 urls on index.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I search alot on google but not get any help.

I have 2 urls like this

- domain.com/index.php?page_id=203
- domain.com/index.php?post_id=12

and i need them like this

- domain.com/203/my-page-name.html
- domain.com/12/my-details-name.html

Here my `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?page_id=$1&title=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?post_id=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

Above code always open `page_id`. Is it possible to make it work or may I make another file for details page?

Answer (score 0):

The two rewrite patterns are identical (`^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$`), and Apache has no way of telling the difference between the two.

Consider changing your URI structure to the following:

- Pages: `/id/name.html`, example: `/203/page-name.html`
- Posts: `/posts/id/name.html`, example `/posts/12/post-name.html`

As an alternative, you can use one rule to rewrite to, say, `index.php?id=$1&title=$2`, eliminating the need for two different query parameters.